# How do you send requests to Express backend using React, when that backend is on an actual server?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, mixed-content

My app worked fine when run locally, but now I've started deploying to an external server. When I try to make requests to my backend server using axios, I either get CORS policy blocked, or if I leave the 'baseURL' blank then CORS lets the request through, but adds a '/' at the end of my request, thus preventing me from adding the port number (:4000) at the end and actually communicating with my server.

The Express server is running on port 4000 on say ip address 22.111.22.111, domain name my-website.com, which I can query using curl just fine, and the React app is being served by Nginx and accessed by https.

My Express server looks like this :

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require("cors")
const app = express()
const https = require("https")

app.use(cors())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
        res.send('~ API is working properly!');
})
```

My Axios request looks like this :

```
const response = await axios.get('https://my-website.com:4000')
```

Which results in a CORS blocked response.

Or I can make a request like this :

```
const response = await axios.get(':4000')
```

Which I assume uses the react app's origin to automatically query this URL : `https://my-website.com/:4000`
Which unfortunately doesn't work because axios adds a slash before the port number, and to get rid of this slash I have to manually enter the URL which immediately results in a CORS problem.

Does anyone know how to get around this? I feel like this should be a pretty common way to deploy a website yet none of the answers I have found online have fixed the problem, as adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` attribute to the server does not have any effect on CORS errors.

Comment: I don't think you have to add port if you are using the domain name. Just try `const response = await axios.get('https://my-website.com')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is `https://my-website.com` is where my React app is served, but I'm trying to make a request to my backend Express server which is on that same server but on port 4000.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so just in case anyone ends up in a similar situation here is my solution :
My mistake was that my React app was being served through https but my server was served through http and I was trying to reach it with https, so the URL could not possibly work. Then when I tried to reach it with http I ran into the issue that you can't load resources using http on an https website because that would not be secure (you get a mixed resource error).

So my solution was to also serve my Express server through Nginx so it would be accessible through https, and I ran into the issue that when trying to serve a second location with a non-root path (like /backend), I would get a 404 Not Found error, and the solution there was to instead use `location /backend/` with the trailing slash at the end, and `proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/` with the same trailing slash.